# TypeScript and jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, typescript

I'm trying to get to grips with TypeScript and hit a problem trying to access jqGrid methods within the TS code;

I've the following code;

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/jqgrid/jqgrid.d.ts" />

interface IInvoice {
    taxRate: number;
}

module mInvoice {

  export class Invoice implements IInvoice {

    constructor(public taxRate: number) { };

    updateTotals(): void {
      this.LinesTotal = $('#list').jqGrid('getCol', 'LineTotal', false, 'sum');
      this.LinesGst = $('#list').jqGrid('getCol', 'LineGst', false, 'sum');

      this.DiscountType =  
             .......
    }
  } 
}
```

The jqGrid `sum` methods don't compile.

I've included the /DefinitelyTyped `*.d.ts` file for jqGrid, this worked fine for jQuery.

Is this missing jqGrid method definitions in the `*.d.ts` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes method definition that accepts 4 parameters is missing in that d.ts file.

You can add it yourself by creating your own local jqGrid.d.ts file that will complement existing definitions with needed method declaration, like this:

```
interface JQueryJqGridStatic 
{
    (gridName: string, id: any, param: boolean, method: string): any;
}
```

Or maybe like this, if you prefer to be consistent with their [docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods):

```
interface JQueryJqGridStatic 
{
    (method: string, ...params: any[]): any;
}
```

Hope this helps.